# Как узнать количество индексов в ArrayList

Tags: java, коллекции, arraylist, java-8, index

У меня есть массив:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add("word1");
```

Если я использую функцию `list.size`, то мне выдаст `1`, но я хочу узнать количество индексов;

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("1");
list.add("2");
list.add("3");
System.out.println(list.size());
```

Я хочу узнать сколько лишних ячеек создалось в ArrayList.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под количеством индексов?

Comment: Если добавить 1 элемент к массиву скажем размером 10 то размер массива будет рассчитываться за формулой 10*1.5+1=16. Под количеством индексов я имею ввиду 16. Возможно ли как-то узнать, вывести это число? Для этого случая и для случая в описании.

Comment: Чего? Откуда вы берёте число 16? Почему вы 10 умножаете на 1.5?

Comment: За этой формулой увеличивается размер динамического массива. https://overcoder.net/q/95528/arraylist-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код, который работает не так, как вы хотите

Comment: Я хочу разобраться, как узнать количество лишних ячеек. Задачи как таковой нету, есть только не понимание.

Comment: @roker Есть только неспособность по-человечески объяснить что Вам нужно.

Comment: Я знаю что можно оптимизировать количество слотов используя метод trimToSize, возможно есть способ узнать какое количество элементов он удалил, или как-то по другому.

Comment: @Igor Мне нужно узнать количество лишних ячеек в массиве, что вам не понятно, могу объяснить подробней.

Comment: В массиве 3 ячейки. Не больше, не меньше. ¿Может это проблема XY и вы на самом деле хотите избежать выделения дополнительной памяти, которая пока не будет использоваться элементами массива, и пытаетесь определить объем этой дополнительной памяти?

Comment: @user7860670 да 3 ячейки но, количество сapacity = 10, я хочу узнать как вывести сapacity

Comment: ArrayList не предоставляет таких сведений, так как знание capacity бесполезно для программы. Но при желании наверное поглядеть в отладчике.

Comment: @roker мой ответ вы игнорируете принципиально? Он выводит именно то что вы и хотите - размер Листа и его Capacity при заполнении. Добавьте тогда еще 2 минуса и я его с удовольствием удалю, заодно получу нашивку ))

Comment: @AlekseiGaile прошу прощения, я попробовал ваш способ, он работает. Но мне нужно немного больше времени чтобы понять почему он создаёт capacity не за формулой. И это не я ставил вам минус, у меня не хватает репутации.

Comment: @roker как тут правильно заметили ArrayList не имеет методов для вывода Capacity, поэтому в данном коде используется рефлексия, чтобы получить эти данные.

Comment: @AlekseiGaile мне бы хотелось узнать кто поставил минус, и почему, возможно ваш код работает не корректно. Но пока я вам поставлю плюс, спасибо.

Comment: @roker данной информацией я не располагаю )) код работает корректно, ровно как по документации - при заполнении массива при попытке добавить еще один элемент ArrayList расширяется в 1.5 раза, что и демонстрируется в консоли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данный код покажет размер Листа и его Capacity при заполнении ArrayList:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
            list.add(i);
            System.out.format("Size: %2d, Capacity: %2d%n",
                    list.size(), getCapacity(list));
        }
    }

    static int getCapacity(List<?> l) throws Exception {
        Field dataField = ArrayList.class.getDeclaredField("elementData");
        dataField.setAccessible(true);
        return ((Object[]) dataField.get(l)).length;
    }
```